# FacebookOperationCanceledException not called

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I'm calling the authorize method which does the login to Facebook.

However if a user cancel the login by one of the two:
press the x or pressing the back button, the onFacebookError callback is called and not the onCancel.

Why is this happening? is this a normal Facebook behavior?

If so, how can i catch if the user canceled the login proccess?

while looking through the Facebook code i can see that in order to call the onCancel callback the exception of Facebook should be a FacebookOperationCanceledException.

im using Facebook android sdk v3.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, please report it here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

The only work around I can think of right now is to look at the error message in your onFacebookError method, and filter on the "User canceled log in." message.

Comment: Found another bug about cancel the login process. after entering the username and password, the next page is to acknowledge the permissions , if the user cancels that page, a onFacebookError exception is called but with no message at all. this is a sad moment for Facebook android sdk.

Comment: If you're using 3.0 of the SDK, you should strongly consider using the Session mechanism over the Facebook class (which is now effectively deprecated). You shouldn't see these errors in Session.